# How to create a "stable" URL for a series of livestreams?

Tags: youtube

My organization produces recurring live "class" type videos.  I want to:

1. provide one, unchanging YouTube URL at which people can view either

   - a live List itemList streaming event, or
   - previously recorded videos; and
2. have these available for viewing immediately (or soon) after we are finished with a live class.

Is this possible?  How do I create a Youtube URL, that can be used to view new livestreams as they come out, to provide to attendees?

Comment: The solution might be to use a link shortening service which lets you edit links like tiny.cc

Comment: Thanks, John.  I look forward to using tiny or something to do that.  But first, I want to make sure that the huge long ridiculous URL I shorten is stable.